# I want to navigate with bottom navigation bar

Tags: flutter, dart, uinavigationbar

I have flutter app and in my app I have to show bottom navigatiobar for every page

I am confuse that should I can navigate with with bottom navigation bar or I have to add bottom navigation bar for every page

If I use Navigation I have to use scaffold as parent of all widget so is it any way to navigate with scaffold.

Here is my code:-

```
class WorkerHomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  WorkerHomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  int _selectedPageIndex = 0;

  List<Map<String, dynamic>> get _pages {
    return [
      {"page": SignInScreen(), "name": "PROPERTY", "action": null},
      {
        "page": ChoseRoleScreen(),
        "name": "CHAT",
        "action": ["Search"]
      },
      {"page": LandingPage(), "name": "VIDEO", "action": null},
      {"page": EmployerSignUpScreen(), "name": "PROFILE", "action": null}
    ];
  }

  void _selectPage(int index) {
    _selectedPageIndex = index;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      ),
      body: _pages[_selectedPageIndex]["page"],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        onTap: _selectPage,
        currentIndex: _selectedPageIndex,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(workerNavigationLists[0].icon),
            label: "Property",
            activeIcon: Icon(workerNavigationLists[0].icon),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(workerNavigationLists[1].icon),
            label: "Chat",
            activeIcon: Icon(workerNavigationLists[0].icon),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(workerNavigationLists[0].icon),
            label: "Video",
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(workerNavigationLists[0].icon),
            label: "Profile",
            activeIcon: Icon(workerNavigationLists[0].icon),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my screen:-

```
class SignInMobile extends StatelessWidget {
  SignInMobile({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  final SignInController signInController = Get.find();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
             /// I want to navigate to other page but I want navigation bar in other page also
               
             },
          child: Text("TAP TO NAVIGATE"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: https://www.javatpoint.com/flutter-bottom-navigation-bar

Comment: thanks for your reply Anmol but I want to navigate with bottom nav bar and your reference suggests how to add bottom navigation bar its totally different thing

Comment: Hey hi @DipakRamoliya just want to ask like you want to keep the  bottomnav constant and when you click on on navbatitem you have go to different page in that selected item itself

Comment: yes sagar I want same as you say

Comment: Ok just wait i will create an example for you. and also demostrate the working in it

Comment: @DipakRamoliya please check the example below that i added.

Answer (score 7):

So from the Discussion I have Create an example

Check this link below for demo:
https://github.com/sagaracharya24/bottomApp.git

So in order to make this implementation you have have a knowledge of following things

1. OnGenerate Route mechanism.
2. GlobalKeys and NavigatorState.
3. Know how Offstage widget works under the hood.

What you will get from the Example:

1. Each Page maintains the stack of pages as per BottomBarItem.
2. If you are deep inside the nested pages and click in the same item, it will remove all the pages and com back to the main page.

I have also add the sample Gif To show you the app is working.

[image]

Let me know the if it works for you thanks.

Comment: I've gone through your implementation and with few twerks I got it working. 
anyone who is willing to have the same behaviour as shown above, should try this. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use [persistent_bottom_nav_bar](https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar) to achieve your expectation. Do as follows:

```
late PersistentTabController _controller;
 @override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = PersistentTabController(initialIndex: 0);
   
  }
     List<PersistentBottomNavBarItem> _navBarsItems() {
    return [
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: Image.asset('assets/logowhite.png', height: 30, width: 30),
        inactiveIcon:
            Image.asset('assets/logowhite.png', height: 30, width: 30),
        title: "Vesvusa",
        textStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        activeColorPrimary: MyTheme.grey,
        activeColorSecondary: Colors.white,
        contentPadding: 5,
        inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.white,
        inactiveColorSecondary: Colors.white,
        routeAndNavigatorSettings: RouteAndNavigatorSettings(
          initialRoute: '/dashboard',
          routes: {
            '/newsevents': (context) => NewsListScreen(
                menuScreenContext: context,
                hideMainAppBar: hideMainAppBar,
                itemCount: null),
            '/blogdetails': (context) => BlogDetails(
                  menuScreenContext: context,
                  hideMainAppBar: hideMainAppBar,
                ),
            '/videoslist': (context) => VideosList(menuScreenContext: context),
            '/bookings': (context) => Bookings(menuScreenContext: context),
            '/lookstheme': (context) => LooksTheme(menuScreenContext: context),
            '/catalog': (context) => Catalog(menuScreenContext: context),
            '/productdetails': (context) =>
                ProductDetails(menuScreenContext: context),
          },
        ),
      ),
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: Image.asset(
          'assets/search.png',
          height: 25,
          width: 25,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        inactiveIcon: Image.asset(
          'assets/search.png',
          height: 25,
          width: 25,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        title: ("Search"),
        activeColorPrimary: MyTheme.grey,
        activeColorSecondary: Colors.white,
        contentPadding: 5,
        inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.white,
        inactiveColorSecondary: Colors.white,
        routeAndNavigatorSettings: const RouteAndNavigatorSettings(
          initialRoute: '/search',
          routes: {
//            '/first': (context) => MainScreen2(),
//            '/second': (context) => MainScreen3(),
          },
        ),
      ),
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: Image.asset(
          'assets/favourite.png',
          height: 25,
          width: 25,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        inactiveIcon: Image.asset(
          'assets/favourite.png',
          height: 25,
          width: 25,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        title: ("Favorite"),
        activeColorPrimary: MyTheme.grey,
        activeColorSecondary: Colors.white,
        contentPadding: 5,
        inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.white,
        inactiveColorSecondary: Colors.white,
        textStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        routeAndNavigatorSettings: const RouteAndNavigatorSettings(
          initialRoute: '/favorite',
          routes: {
//              '/first': (context) => MainScreen2(),
//              '/second': (context) => MainScreen3(),
          },
        ),
//          onPressed: (context) {
//            pushDynamicScreen(context,
//                screen: SampleModalScreen(), withNavBar: true);
//          }
      ),
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: Image.asset(
          'assets/cart.png',
          height: 25,
          width: 25,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        inactiveIcon: Image.asset(
          'assets/cart.png',
          height: 25,
          width: 25,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        title: ("Cart"),
        activeColorPrimary: MyTheme.grey,
        activeColorSecondary: Colors.white,
        contentPadding: 5,
        inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.white,
        inactiveColorSecondary: Colors.white,
        textStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        routeAndNavigatorSettings: const RouteAndNavigatorSettings(
          initialRoute: '/cart',
          routes: {
//            '/first': (context) => MainScreen2(),
//            '/second': (context) => MainScreen3(),
          },
        ),
      ),
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: Image.asset(
          'assets/profile.png',
          height: 25,
          width: 25,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        inactiveIcon: Image.asset(
          'assets/profile.png',
          height: 25,
          width: 25,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        title: ("Profile"),
        activeColorPrimary: MyTheme.grey,
        activeColorSecondary: Colors.white,
        contentPadding: 5,
        inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.white,
        inactiveColorSecondary: Colors.white,
        textStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        routeAndNavigatorSettings: RouteAndNavigatorSettings(
          initialRoute: '/profile',
          routes: {
            '/orders': (context) => MyOrders(
                  menuScreenContext: context,
                ),
            '/loginsecurity': (context) => LoginSecurity(
                  menuScreenContext: context,
                ),
            '/payment': (context) => Payment(
                  menuScreenContext: context,
                ),
            '/message': (context) => Messages(
                  menuScreenContext: context,
                ),
            '/devices': (context) => Devices(
                  menuScreenContext: context,
                ),
            '/devices': (context) => Devices(
                  menuScreenContext: context,
                ),
            '/inboxdetails': (context) => InboxDetails(
                  menuScreenContext: context,
                ),
            '/loyalty': (context) => Loyalty(menuScreenContext: context),
          },
        ),
      ),
    ];
  }

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: MyTheme.themeColor,
      appBar:  AppBar(
              elevation: 0,
              iconTheme: IconThemeData(
                color: MyTheme.grey,
              ),
              centerTitle: true,
              backgroundColor: MyTheme.themeColor,
              title: Image.asset("assets/titles.png", height: 60, width: 100),
              actions: [
                Builder(
                  builder: (context) {
                    return InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer();
                        },
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 20, 0),
                          child: Icon(Icons.notifications_none_outlined,
                              color: MyTheme.grey),
                        ));
                  },
                )
              ],
            ),
      drawer: MyDrawer(),
      endDrawer: const NotificationDrawer(),
      body: PersistentTabView(
        context,
        controller: _controller,
        screens: _buildScreens(),
        items: _navBarsItems(),
        confineInSafeArea: true,
        backgroundColor: MyTheme.themeColor,
        handleAndroidBackButtonPress: true,
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
        stateManagement: true,

        hideNavigationBarWhenKeyboardShows: true,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
        popActionScreens: PopActionScreensType.once,
        bottomScreenMargin: 0.0,
        onWillPop: (context) async {
          await showDialog(
              context: context!,
              useSafeArea: false,
              builder: (context) => CommonAlert());
          return false;
        },
        selectedTabScreenContext: (context) {
          context = context;
        },
        hideNavigationBar: _hideNavBar,

        popAllScreensOnTapOfSelectedTab: true,

        itemAnimationProperties: const ItemAnimationProperties(
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
          curve: Curves.ease,
        ),
        screenTransitionAnimation: const ScreenTransitionAnimation(
          animateTabTransition: true,
          curve: Curves.ease,
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
        ),
        navBarStyle:
            NavBarStyle.style7, // Choose the nav bar style with this property
      ),
    );
  }
```

You can navigate to other page doing this

```
 pushNewScreen(context,
                              screen: Loyalty(
                                menuScreenContext: context,
                              ),pageTransitionAnimation:PageTransitionAnimation.scale);
                        },
```

Comment: thanks Nbn,so it mean I have to add routes for bottom navigation if I was in one screen and I want to navigate to second screen it will navigate me with bottom navigation bar is it safe for big project?

Comment: yeah it works for all screens of your application

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to add `BottomNavigationBar` in all pages if you define it in your `HomePage` (Your first page) only.

Comment: but I do it right but I have 40 page application and I am not able to show bottom bar in all page

Comment: As suggested by @vaidarbhi if you define it in your homepage and just import that homepage to all the other pages, you can achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

if you dont want to use any packages in order to maintain the appsize or reduce it,  please use the inbuilt flutter bottom navigation

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Mynavigation extends StatefulWidget {
  const Mynavigation({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Mynavigation> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<Mynavigation> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  static const TextStyle optionStyle =
  TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
   List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
   Home(),Business(),School(), Settings()
    
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('BottomNavigationBar Sample'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.business),
            label: 'Business',
            backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.school),
            label: 'School',
            backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
            label: 'Settings',
            backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

you do notice this line  having
Home(),Business(),School(), Settings(),

those should be individual pages where you want to navigate to.SO PLEASE change them to point to the pages you want to use.

and then one more thing just replace Mynavigation with WorkerHomeScreen and you are good to go,

if your using flutter sdk >2.12.0
please use on this line

```
static const List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
```

else if your sdk is below 2.12.0 then use

```
 List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
```

incase of any question, I will be waiting

Good luck bro

Comment: thanks for your answer smith but I want to navigate like we navigate in YouTube with bottombar this is not my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add BottomNevigatioBar using scaffold property and add multiple Page to the List. Hope you got your solution

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:traveling/helpers/AppColors.dart';
import 'package:traveling/screens/Employee/home/Home.dart';
import 'package:traveling/screens/Employee/profile/Profile.dart';
import 'package:traveling/screens/Employee/setting/Setting.dart';



class EmployeeBottomNavBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const EmployeeBottomNavBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _EmployeeBottomNavBarState createState() => _EmployeeBottomNavBarState();
}

class _EmployeeBottomNavBarState extends State<EmployeeBottomNavBar> {
  int pageIndex = 0;
  bool visible = true;

  List<Widget> pageList = <Widget>[EmployeeHome(), Profile(leadingIcon: false,), Setting()];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: pageList[pageIndex],
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
            fixedColor: Colors.redAccent[400],
            currentIndex: pageIndex,
            onTap: (value) {
              setState(() {
                pageIndex = value;
              });
            },
            // type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
            items: [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(

                  activeIcon: Container(
                    height: 40,
                    width: 80,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      color: Color(0xff2161c0),
                    ),
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.home,
                      color: AppColors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.home,
                    color: Color(0xff2161c0),
                  ),
                  label: ""),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  activeIcon: Container(
                    height: 40,
                    width: 80,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      color: Color(0xff2161c0),
                    ),
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.person,
                      color: AppColors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.person,
                    color: AppColors.baseLightBlueColor,
                  ),
                  label: ""),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  activeIcon: Container(
                    height: 40,
                    width: 80,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      color: AppColors.baseLightBlueColor,
                    ),
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.settings,
                      color: AppColors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.settings,
                    color: AppColors.baseLightBlueColor,
                  ),
                  label: ""),
            ]
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: no this is not my answer