# Is there anything like fragment in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

I want to use the navigation bar in a Flutter app.
I couldn't find anything like a fragment in Flutter.

I know switching between nav menus can be done by condition.
I want a solution like Fragment in Android, opening a new route in a specific portion of the screen.

Comment: Check if this one helps you out : https://stackoverflow.com/a/70589881/12000053